# Javascript - Change src at onmouseover and onmouseout

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmouseout

I want to do that onmouseover change the image and onmouseout it returns the default image. I use this code:

```
<div class="home-social-share">
<div style="margin-right:15px;width:11px;float:left;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>','Condividi su Facebook','height=300, width=750,scrollbars=no, resizable=yes')">
        <img src="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/themes/pponline/images/fbshareoff.png" alt="Condividi su Facebook" title="Condividi su Facebook" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/themes/pponline/images/fbshare.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/themes/pponline/images/fbshareoff.png'">
    </a>
</div>
<div style="float:left;margin-right:15px;">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('http://twitter.com/share?text=<?php the_title(); ?> &bull; Prima Pagina Online&amp;url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>','Condividi su Twitter','height=300, width=500,scrollbars=no, resizable=yes')">
        <img src="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/themes/pponline/images/tt-shareoff.png" alt="Condividi su Twitter" title="Condividi su Twitter" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/themes/pponline/images/tt-share.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/themes/pponline/images/tt-shareoff.png'" />
</a>
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>/#disqus_thread">
        <img src="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/themes/pponline/images/pencil-off.png" alt="Commenta l'articolo" title="Scrivi un commento sull'articolo" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/themes/pponline/images/pencil.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/themes/pponline/images/pencil-off.png'" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Now, it works the onclick functions but the images remains the same, so the onmouseover and onmouseout doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: this is poorly written.   Segregate Javascript FROM the Markup, so it is more human readable.   I can read it, but i could see how you can get lost as to why it isnt working

Comment: What do you mean with ["doesn't work"](http://jsfiddle.net/WMHdV/1/)??? (Added the whole code to a fiddle.)

Comment: images changing for me on `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`

Comment: @Teemu: Well, in jsfiddle seems to work but if you go on my website (www.primapaginaonline.it) you can see that the images doesn't become red when you hover them, or at least on my pc.

Comment: The fiddle contains exactly your code. Please post something with which we can reproduce the issue, otherwise your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Try to go to the website, and you see that the code doesn't work

Comment: Please re-read my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure whether your using Jquery or not, so I'll include examples of both.

```
<img id="change" src="picture" alt="picture.jpg">
```

Jquery -

```
$('#change').on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'picture2');
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'picture');
});
```

Javascript -

```
document.getElementById('change').addEventListener("onmouseover", function() { 
  this.src = 'picture2';
}).addEventListener("onmouseout", function() {
  this.src = 'picture';
});
```

That should get you going!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events because it always works.

Example:

```
<img src="picture" onmouseover="this.src='picture2'" onmouseout="this.src='picture3'">
```

Also see http://helplogger.blogspot.be/2012/05/create-rollover-image-effect-change.html

Answer (score 0):

The code from your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WMHdV/1/) and the one from your website have some differences.

This code is from your website:

```
<img src="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/themes/pponline/images/pencil-off.png?b33912" alt="Commenta l'articolo" title="Scrivi un commento sull'articolo" onmouseover="this.src=" http:="" www.primapaginaonline.it="" wp-content="" themes="" pponline="" images="" pencil.png?b33912""="" onmouseout="this.src=" pencil-off.png?b33912""="">
```

This is easy to get lost with all this code in a simple tag but if you look closely you will see some of the problems.

First, you have double quotes inside double quotes:

```
onmouseout="this.src=" pencil-off.png?b33912""=""
```

And some of these double quotes are not supposed to be there, ex. `http:=""` in

```
onmouseover="this.src=" http:="" www.primapaginaonline.it=""
```

Clean this up and it will works!